# How to run a non-spark code on databricks cluster?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am able to pull the data from databricks connect and run spark jobs perfectly. My question is how to run non-spark or native python code on remote cluster. Not sharing the code due to confidentiality.

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#limitations

Answer (score 1):

When you're using databricks connect, then your local machine is a driver of your Spark job, so non-Spark code will be **always executed on your local machine**.  If you want to execute it remotely, then you need to package it as wheel/egg, or upload Python files onto DBFS (for example, via [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli.html)) and execute your code as Databricks job (for example, using the [Run Submit command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-submit) of Jobs REST API, or [create a Job with databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli.html) and use `databricks jobs run-now` to execute it)